# Facebook Login keeps repeating asking permissions React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-native-fbsdk

I'm a newbie in `React Native` and struggling to make a `Facebook` login for my app.

I finished configuring all the requirements for my app, `Firebase` and `Facebook` for developers.

The thing is when I pressed login, at the first time, it kept repeating again the Login permission. Until the `data` receive the `accessToken` and `id`, my app might/might not navigate to the **Main** screen (login succeed). But just 1 second later, the screen prompted and showed the Login Manager again. And it keeps repeating that. I really don't know why.

Is it something wrong with my code?. I'm thinking it kept repeating because It must do that until it gets the data need ( promise resolved)

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    ImageBackground,
    StyleSheet,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import {
    Layout
} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton, statusCodes } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { LoginButton, LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

const GoogleLogIn = (props) => {

    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
    const [isLogIn, setIsLogIn] = useState(false);

    // Facebook log in
    const _facebookLogin = async () => {
        try{
            const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
            console.log(result);

            if(result.isCancelled){
                console.log('Login is cancelled');
            }else if(result.grantedPermissions){
                console.log('DONE')
                const data =  await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                console.log(data);
                const cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
                const firebaseCred = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
                setIsLogIn(true);
                setUserInfo(data.userID);
                props.navigation.navigate('AppNavigator', {screen: 'Welcome'})
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.background}>

            <LoginButton
                onLoginFinished={_facebookLogin}
                onLogoutFinished={() => console.log('Logout!')}
            />

        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})
export default GoogleLogIn;
```

Here's the *weird* behavior:

[Error_repeating asking permissions for login Facebook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=166puWogn6Z49qUx3-dB4K0Fy9-NjSugf)

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: possible to show more codes from this facebook login page? i suppose something to do with you webview / state?

Comment: Yes I edited with the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I found it worked well. You can put this in a button for customizing

```
const  facebookLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
                (res) => {
                    if(res.isCancelled){
                        console.log('Something went wrong, please try again');
                    }else{
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                            async (data) => {
                              console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                              const cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
                              const firebaseCred = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
                              setIsLogIn(true);
                              setUserInfo(data.userID);
                              props.navigation.navigate('AppNavigator', {screen: 'Welcome'})
                            }

                          )
                    }
                }
            )
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `useState` function seems to cause rendering again and cause problems.
You can try use `useCallback`

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that
>   only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful
>   when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on
>   reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g.
>   `shouldComponentUpdate`).

**Usage**

```js
const _facebookLogin =  useCallback( async () => {
      try{
          const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
          console.log(result);

          if(result.isCancelled){
              console.log('Login is cancelled');
          }else if(result.grantedPermissions){
              console.log('DONE')
              const data =  await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
              console.log(data);
              const cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
              const firebaseCred = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
              setIsLogIn(true);
              setUserInfo(data.userID);
              props.navigation.navigate('AppNavigator', {screen: 'Welcome'})
          }
      }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
      }
  },[])
```

Comment: Thank you Hong so much for the answer. But the error still can't be solved. Would you mind looking the code again ( I updated it fully ). Please help me !

Comment: @Marwin  The log of the video you attach is not up to date, it seems to show the old log. So I can't understand it right.

Comment: Sorry Hong. I provided a solution I've just found out